# Eclipse Android text scrolling

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview

I can't find out what the code required to make a text box scroll-able in my app.

I've seen answers like this on here:

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

And then use:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

But then I get an error about the AN_INTEGER line? thanks.
in your code.

Comment: where you have declared AN_INTEGER variable?

Comment: "Syntax error on token "setMovementMethod", = expected after this token" - I get this error, I apologise I'm very, very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The value you assign to `maxLines` should be an actual integer i.e. "5" not "AN_INTEGER".

Comment: In the Java when I add that line above it gets the error "Syntax error on token "setMovementMethod", = expected after this token" next to it.